# Как решить проблему с бесконечной прокруткой с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css

Имеется JS код, выполняющий функцию подгрузки контента по мере прокрутки страницы пользователем, работает исправно. Ситуация в том, что при четком задании конкретной высоты блоку, в котором ожидается бесконечная прокрута (конечно же она зависит от количества сохраненных даннх), работает всё исправно.

Проблема в том, что задание четкой высоты блок `height: 100vh` или `height: 300px` является, мягко говоря, некорректным решением с точки зрения адаптационного шаблона. С помощью задания блоку свойства как `height: 100%` функция бесконечно прокрутки уже не будет работать.

Так вот вопрос в том, как заставить работать `flexbox` и функцию бесконечной прокрутки без использования указания четкой свойств высоты блока как  `height: 100vh` или `height: 300px`?

Макет страницы:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#workspace {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#header,
#footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 56px;
}

#stretch-box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#left-box {
  min-width: 300px;
}

#right-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  //height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header id="header">
    // data
  </header>

  <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
  <section class="content">
    <div id="stretch-box">

      <!-- LEFT BOX -->
      <div id="left-box">
        // data
      </div>

      <!-- RIGHT BOX -->
      <div id="right-box">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer id="footer">
    // data
  </footer>
</div>
```

**Без** использовании свойства `height: 100vh;` для `#right-box`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**При использовании** свойства `height: 100vh;` для `#right-box`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал добавлять в каждый родительский блок относительно `#right-box` свойство `height: 100%;`, а потом дополнительно `overflow: auto;` - безрезультатно.

Comment: Не понятно, в чем именно проблема. Вы пишите про "некорректное решение с точки зрения адаптационного шаблона", но не корректна сама идея прокручивать блок с длинным контентом — на тачскрине два скрола (документа и блока) будут неприятно непредсказуемо срабатывать. Почему бы не прокручивать сразу всю страницу, закрепив на экране отдельные элементы интерфейса?

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, всё возможно, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это организовать. То, что пробовал я, не дает ожидаемого результата.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, просьба давать конкретные ответы (код). По моему мнению (предполагаю, что и по мнению большинства) от абстрактных рассуждений толку мало.

Comment: Глядя на скриншоты, очевидно что не нужно указывать высоту контейнера и overflow: auto — пусть контент подгружается при прокрутке, просто скроллим страницу и всё. Если нужно, чтобы шапка не прокручивалась, можно добавить ей position:fixed

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, в этом то и дело, что страница просто не скроллится.

Comment: Если в первой выдаче достаточно контента, чтобы появилась полоса прокрутки, и если у контейнера не заданы свойства height и overflow, то страница будет скроллится сама по себе.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, нет, не будет, не работает скролл без задания высоты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
+:root {
+  --header-height: 56px;
+}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#workspace {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#header, #footer {
  display: flex;
- height: 56px;
+ height: var(--header-height);
}

#stretch-box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#left-box {
  min-width: 300px;
}

#right-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  //height: 100vh;
+ height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) * 2);
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```